# Should I use VACUUM on a SQLite db with a log-structured filesystem?

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

I'm runnig a SQLite database on nilfs (which is a log-structured filesystem). Every now and then I delete old records, so that the size of the database never surpass a certain amount.
But since the filesystem is log-structured (also, I'm running from flash memory) I am uncertain if I should also run VACUUM command or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the order of pages in the file has no relation to the order of pages on the disk, reordering the file does not make sense.